# Regex - stylistically "converting" text through multiple character replacement

Tags: regex

First of all, I'm not sure how exactly to correctly phrase what I'm looking for in the title, so please bear with me.

There's a way to imitate the "Bulgarian stylistic variation of Cyrillic" with certain Unicode characters. Example:

```
Шлюз Кеймбридж: счупвах цъфтящ гьон
```

Becomes:

```
Шʌюз Кеŭмбрugж: счуnϐах ᶙъфmяɰ ᴤьон
```

I'd need to do this on mobile, and making an Android keyboard layout that does this is a lot of work, so I might use Regex to do this for now. How would I do a conversion like this below, for an entire text?

```
Л > Λ
в > ϐ
г > ᴤ
д > g
и > u
й > ŭ
к > k
л > ʌ
п > n
т > m
ц > ᶙ
ш > ɯ
щ > ɰ
```

I mostly picked regex because there are ways to use it online (which is convenient on mobile). I'm open to any other ways to do this quickly and easily on Android.

Comment: Do you need a regex answer or is any answer in any language fine?

Comment: You could just replace the individual characters with the new characters. You don't really need regex for this.

Comment: Regex doesn't "do" anything to the string, it only matches parts or all of it, so regex will be of no use to you. Instead, you need standard character by character string replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, guys. I assumed regex would be able to do this, and I mostly picked it because there's ways to use regex online (which is convenient on mobile, where I would need to do so).

Are there any better options to quickly do "standard character by character string replacement" on mobile?

Comment: @barbiedolphin what language are you coding in? Please add the language tag to the question.